Are both sentences below correct?

Where do you see yourself five years from now?
Where do you see yourself in five years from now?


Please let us know your doubts.

You can say:

Where do you see yourself five years from now?

or

Where do you see yourself in five years?

In five years from now seems to be used pretty commonly as well, but it's a little redundant and I think not as elegant as the other two. Looking at COCA it's both less common (4728 hits for "in a year" and only 28 from "in a year from now"), and the sources are generally not as good quality - mostly Internet posts or quotes of someone speaking.
